# Comparison of French and English Tenses

Tags: grammaire, anglais, temps-grammatical

What are some general sources (and discussions inside FSE) in which the French and English Tenses are thoroughly compared?

For instance what are the guidelines of conveying in English the Imperfect, Past Historic (passé simple) and Perfect (passé composé) and vice versa (English tenses to French ones)?

Something along the lines of the article: http://www.academypublication.com/issues/past/tpls/vol04/11/15.pdf
but writing from a French perspective (grammar book, online text, etc.).

Comment: Je crois que c'est plus général que Français/Anglais. Ce serait plutôt langues italiques / langues germaniques.

Comment: And even better than either would be a solid foundation in linguistics — be able to define and give examples of different tenses, aspects, moods, voices, and person-number-gender paradigms. The comparison between any two languages, including one's own (such a great tool for analysis), would then be possible on one's own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many sources on Internet comparing English and French tenses.

One of the best link I found was [Tableau des temps Anglais/Français](http://florenceduperray.free.fr/wp-content/uploads/TABLEAU-DES-TEMPS.pdf).